# is there a new way of linking Font awesome to my project?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am adding my font-awesome link to my Html page and it is not working and I have checked all my former projects too in which it was working before but found out they have all stopped working. Help out!!!!!

Comment: I believe you've gotten the ID in their official website, and tried the link with the ID that you got there. Or you didn't do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this it's work <link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

Comment: Thanks, how did you come across this? I have been racking my head